# .remove() not removing item in Jquery when checkbox unselected

Tags: javascript, jquery, django-templates

I have checkbox that append an item when selected but will not remove it when deselected,
just to clarify the appending part is working fine.

the jQuery :

```
   $('.category-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]').click(function (){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
             // Add the element to the div with an id identifier
             $('.items').append('<div id="[{{category.id}}]">123123</div>');
        } else  {
             // Remove the element from the div targeted by the id identifier
             $('.items #[{{category.id}}]').remove();
        }
    });
```

the template:

```
<div class="inventory-content">
    <div class='category'>
        <div>Categories</div>
        <div class='category-checkbox'>
            {%for category in categories%}
            <input type="checkbox" id="{{category.id}}" name="{{category.name}}" value="{{category.id}}">
            <label for="{{category.name}}"> {{category.name}}</label><br>
            {%endfor%}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='items'></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Whenever doing web development, when something doesn't work, look in the devtools console to see if there are any errors. In this case, you'll see an error along the lines of `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .items #[xyz]`. That's an invalid ID selector. You could use `$('.items [id="[{{category.id}}]"]').remove();` instead.

Comment: Thank you for the advice i highly appreciate it @T.J.Crowder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you would run into problem with duplicated ids, once you did your append. Second jquery don't know what `{{category.id}}` refers to.

You could do it like:

```
$('.category-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    // Add the element to the div with an id identifier
    $('.items').append(`<div id="item_${this.id}">123123</div>`);
  } else {
    // Remove the element from the div targeted by the id identifier
    $(`#item_${this.id}`).remove();
  }
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$('.category-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    // Add the element to the div with an id identifier
    $('.items').append(`<div id="item_${this.id}">123123</div>`);
  } else {
    // Remove the element from the div targeted by the id identifier
    $(`#item_${this.id}`).remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inventory-content">
  <div class='category'>
    <div>Categories</div>
    <div class='category-checkbox'>
      <input type="checkbox" id="cat1" name="cat1" value="cat1">
      <label for="cat1"> cat1</label><br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="cat2" name="cat2" value="cat2">
      <label for="cat2"> cat2</label><br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="cat3" name="cat3" value="cat3">
      <label for="cat3"> cat3</label><br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='items'></div>

</div>
```